# How to choose the highest values on a pandas dataframe, without choosing the same column and row more than once

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `pandas` dataframe that looks like this:

```
           0           1           2           3
0   0.371292    0.198658    0.178688    0.164981
1   0.262219    0.461267    0.447531    0.194239
2   0.412508    0.105518    0.254549    0.471136
```

I would like to choose the `n` larger numbers, where `n = min(len(df), len(df.columns))` together with the row name and column name. The condition that  all `n` numbers, must be on different `row` **and** `column` one from another.

In the above example, the numbers `[0.471136, 0.461267, 0.371292]` should be chosen together with their respective `(row, column)`, so `[(2,3), (1,1), (0,0)]`
The reason that `0.371292` is chosen over the `0.447531` even though `0.447531` is bigger than `0.412508`, is because `row 1` has already been used before (for `0.461267`)

Is there a pythonic way of doing that ?

Comment: Your example is confusing, 0.471137 is not at (3, 2) but it is at (2, 3). Thus, 0.412508 should not be the third number since they are on the same row. Instead 0.371292 should be the third number.

Comment: @Dorku You are right. I edited the quesiton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that would make sure you don't choose values from either the same row **nor** the same column:

```
n = min(len(df), len(df.columns))
for i in range(n):
    t = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars="index")
    max_cell = t.iloc[t.value.idxmax()]
    row = max_cell["index"]
    col = max_cell["variable"]
    print(f"max cell is {max_cell}")
    df.drop(row, axis=0, inplace = True)
    df.drop(col, axis=1, inplace = True)
```